# Using int and floating gives different value of LegendreP

Tags: numerical-methods, legendre-polynomials, floating-point

I should post this in mathematica forum, sorry for the inconvenience.
When I use LegendreP at mathematica 10.0, I found weird a thing happening.

```
In[693]:= N[LegendreP[300, Cos[50/360 2 Pi]]]

Out[693]= -1.04451*10^61
```

If

```
In[692]:= N[LegendreP[300, Cos[50.0/360 2 Pi]]]

Out[692]= -0.0402969
```

Obviously, $-0.0403$ is the right answer. Why has such big difference?

I also tried like

```
In[694]:= N[LegendreP[300.0, Cos[50/360 2 Pi]]]

Out[694]= -0.0402969
```

And also

```
In[695]:= N[LegendreP[30, Cos[50/360 2 Pi]]]

Out[695]= 0.126799
```

Looks if $n$ is smaller than $50$, also give a right value.

I totally confused....

Comment: Numerical analysts might attribute this sort of loss of accuracy to [subtractive cancellation](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Weaknesses/).  I don't think you've provided enough detail to treat this as "debugging help", but maybe it just needs a bit of tweaking.  Is this open source software?

Comment: "When I use..." Where? Where do you use this? Help people help you. In a lot of programming languages, $50/360$ is integer division, and thus returns $0,$ and $50.0/360$ is floating point division. But without knowing the context, you haven't help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Catastrophic cancellation is happening here. The largest coefficient of $P_{300}(x)$ has magnitude larger than $10^{112}$; that's enormous! Even after plugging in the value of $x$, the largest term still has magnitude greater than $10^{76}$. You either need *lots* of precision or clever symbolic manipulation in order to get anything vaguely resembling the correct answer.

In particular, this cannot be computed in the naive way using machine precision arithmetic.

If you ask mathematica to specifically give you some number of digits of precision, it knows how to achieve it:

```
In[1]:= N[LegendreP[300, Cos[50/360 2 Pi]], 3]

Out[1]= -0.0403
```